# Memory efficient type to store 8 bytes and 2 ushort values

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-core, types, memory-management

I need to create an array of rows. Each row will consist of eight 1-byte numbers (0-255), and two 2-byte ushort numbers (0-65535). I will keep millions (if not billions) of such rows at the same time in memory. What's the best type to use to construct such row If I'm focus on optimizing memory usage? I use 64bit operating system.

I was thinking about simple `Tuple`, like this:

```
new Tuple<byte[], ushort, ushort>(byteArray, 1, 2);
```

or a struct:

```
public struct Row
{
    public Row(byte[] bytes, ushort val1, ushort val2)
    {
        Bytes = bytes;
        Val1 = val1;
        Val2 = val2;
    }

    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; } = new byte[8];
    public ushort Val1 { get; set; }
    public ushort Val2 { get; set; }
}
```

or a struct, but without byte array? Like this:

```
public struct Row
{
    public byte B1 { get; set; }
    public byte B2 { get; set; }
    public byte B3 { get; set; }
    public byte B4 { get; set; }
    public byte B5 { get; set; }
    public byte B6 { get; set; }
    public byte B7 { get; set; }
    public byte B8 { get; set; }

    public ushort Val1 { get; set; }
    public ushort Val2 { get; set; }
}
```

I think that data itself will take 12bytes (or maybe 16bytes?). But I'm not sure how much memory will be used in other stuff that I'm not aware of. Like array length? Should I use `List` instead of array?

Should I avoid using array, and store each byte in separate property?

Should I use `int` instead of `ushort`? If one row would take 16bytes anyway, isn't it better to just use `int` for Val1 and Val2?

One caveat, once this list of billions such rows is created, some values will be changed/updated later in the algorithm. Not sure if it matters when choosing a perfect type for this.

Thanks for suggestions and help!

Comment: That's many many questions in one. Why not create sophisticated tests to see if different options meet your expectations / requirements and then decide for what works for you?

Comment: A couple things: if space complexity is very important, stick to the array over the List<T> unless you absolutely need methods that list provides. Lists aren't huge, but they by definition will have some more overhead. I see you number specifically `B1` to `B8`...If you define the array as having fixed size `[8]` then I think there is no issue with using an array vs singular fields. On the contrary I *would* use the array so that I can implement my own [Indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) for that array property

Comment: Also this may just be personal preference but I always go for structs or named tuples simply bc is makes things a bit more clear. I love regular nameless tuples in LINQ tho

Comment: _"some values will be changed/updated later in the algorithm. Not sure if it matters when choosing a perfect type for this"_ - it in fact does matter. But it can be handled in different ways. You could test if using immutable structs is superior to mutable ones in your case. In former case, youd replace in case of mutation.

Answer (score 0):

The last option looks like the most efficient. If you want to make it work as if there was an array you could try this:

```
struct A {
    private ulong bytes;
    // allows you to access the bytes like this is an array
    public byte this[int i] {
        get => (byte)(bytes >> (i * 8));
        set {
            bytes &= ~(0b11111111 << (i * 8));
            bytes |= value << (i * 8);
        }
    }
    public ushort ushort1;
    public ushort ushort2;
}
```